# EvaluateJavaScript only allow a return type of String?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview, kotlin

I made a common function (in Kotlin) that I could invoke the JavaScript function per the command given.

```
    fun evaluateJsFromNative(command: String, 
        webView: WebView, function: (value : String) -> Unit ) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return $command; })();") {
            s -> function(s)
        }
    }
```

However, it only allow value `String` as the return type. If I wanted it to be something more generic, that I could have return type of Boolean, Int, or even nothing, how could I make this even more generic?

E.g. I can't do this... it will error in the `function(s)` stating the `s` need to be a `String`

```
    fun evaluateJsFromNative(command: String, 
        webView: WebView, function: (value : Boolean) -> Unit ) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return $command; })();") {
            s -> function(s)
        }
    }
```

Comment: your question is confusing, the function evaluateJFromNative does not return String, it returns Unit, and your function parameter method does not return String, it accepts String parameters.  please provide a use case of how you plan to call it and what you expect the results to be, that would be more helpful.

Comment: Add more details, hopes that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you have defined your function to take a Boolean parameter, but you are passing a String parameter at `s -> function(s)`.  It is a String because that is how `WebView.evalueateJavascript()` is defined.

You cannot change the type of function that `webView.evaluateJavascript()` accepts.  You can, however, convert the String parameter to Boolean and call your function with that.

For example (using your second implementation taking Boolean):

```
fun evaluateJsFromNative(command: String, 
    webView: WebView, function: (value : Boolean) -> Unit ) {
    webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return $command; })();") {
        s -> function(s.toBoolean())
    }
}

// you would call it like this...
    evaluateJsFromNative(mycommand, mywebview) {
        Log.d("SomeTag","Value=$it")
    }
```

**But** this is highly simplified because you could supply it **any** string as a command, including non-Javascript.  The docs say the function parameter of `evaluateJavascript()` will only be called if the Javascript evaluates to something other than `null` (**note**, it will call your function with the value `'null'` if your WebView does not have Javascript enabled).  So, even if and assuming you pass good Javascript, that returns non-null, `s` may still not successfully convert to a `Boolean`.  In other words, you have a lot of work to do to handle bad input parameters, and handling types you don't expect.

But you asked about something more generic.  So here is a try; you would have to expand the `when` statement for all the types you support (and of course error handling).

```
fun <T : Any> evaluateJsFromNative(command: String,
                             webView: WebView, klass: Class<T>, function: (value : Any?) -> Unit ) {
    webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return $command; })();") {
        s -> if (s.convert(klass) != null) function(s.convert(klass)!!)
    }
}

fun <T> String.convert(klass: Class<T>) : Any? {
    when (klass.name.toString()) {
        "boolean" -> return this.toBoolean()
        else -> return null
    }
}

// call it like this...
    evaluateJsFromNative(mycommand, mywebview, Boolean::class.java) {
        Log.d("SomeTag","Value=$it")
    }
```

This example requires that you specify the type you expect from the Javascript, and then you must parse it from a string to the type you expect.  And you must pre-define what types you will support.  It would be nice if the conversion were simpler, but alas, there isn't this kind of type conversion in Kotlin according to [this post in the Kotlin forums](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/type-conversions/828)

I hope this helps